# Rapi.dll / OpenNETCF Invoke example

Tags: c#, windows-ce, rapi

I'm failing to use the Invoke method of the OpenNETCF Rapi.dll.
Can somebody please post an example? I can't seem to find one anywhere on the web.
Other function calls worked fine, but I couldn't figure out Invoke.
(dllPath was OK)

- MyDll is in the root of the CE device.
- It has a FindAndKill method which needs one string argument

I've tried this:

```
var rapi = new CODMrapi.CODMrapi(dllPath);
var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
rapi.Connect();
byte[] inputData = encoding.GetBytes(fileName);
byte[] outputData;
rapi.Connect();
rapi.Invoke("\\MyDll.dll", "FindAndKill", inputData, out outputData);
rapi.Disconnect();
```

Comment: And what's the resulting behavior? What's coming in to your DLL?

Comment: FindAndKill method in the DLL has a string argument, which is a filename of an executable file. Finds that process and kills it.

Comment: Yes, but is your DLL getting loaded? Is the method getting called?  Is data coming into the DLL?

Comment: I don't know these, neither how could I check.

Comment: A simple way would be the strategic use of ::MessageBox calls in the DLL.

Comment: Yeah, did something similar with file creation. The method is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug to determine what's happening.  Add in `::MessageBox` calls to the DllMain and the method to see if the DLL is even getting loaded and if the method is getting called.  If they are not, make sure that your method is publicly exported from the DLL and the name wasn't mangled (dumpbin is a good tool for this)