# How to use RAPI.Invoke to call device winapi method from Desktop app

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-mobile, windows-ce, rapi

I need to get Device Id from a desktop application, where Device is a Windows CE 5.0 based handheld terminal and it is connected to PC.

Getting this information from an application within the device is easy, I can use any of [GetDeviceUniqueID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908781.aspx) or [KernelIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446562.aspx) WinApi methods for example:

```
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private extern static int GetDeviceUniqueID([In, Out] byte[] appdata,
                           int cbApplictionData,
                            int dwDeviceIDVersion,
                            [In, Out] byte[] deviceIDOuput,
                            out uint pcbDeviceIDOutput);

    public byte[] GetDeviceID(string AppString)
    {
        // Call the GetDeviceUniqueID
        byte[] AppData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(AppString);
        int appDataSize = AppData.Length;
        byte[] DeviceOutput = new byte[20];
        uint SizeOut = 20;
        GetDeviceUniqueID(AppData, appDataSize, 1, DeviceOutput, out SizeOut);
        return DeviceOutput;
    }
```

But I need to get this from Desktop application.

There is a sample within Windows Mobile 5.X SDK to get this ID from Desktop app. Since I am using Windows CE that sample does not give an ID (It's for windows mobile).

[image: getDeviceIdSampleOutput]

I believe it is *possible* to use said method from desktop app using RAPI.Invoke() method (Or Opennetcf RAPI). But I can't figure how to use RAPI.Invoke with multi-parameter WinApi method e.g. GetDeviceUniqueID .

I have a sample code, also included C# signature of WinApi method as comment:

```
    //[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    //private extern static int GetDeviceUniqueID([In, Out] byte[] appdata,
    //                       int cbApplictionData,
    //                        int dwDeviceIDVersion,
    //                        [In, Out] byte[] deviceIDOuput,
    //                        out uint pcbDeviceIDOutput);

    private void buttonGetDeviceID_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // RAPI
        RAPI rapi = new RAPI();
        rapi.Connect(true);
        // How do I pass several parameters inside a byte[] ?
        rapi.Invoke(@"\Windows\coredll.dll", "GetDeviceUniqueID", inputData, out outputData);
        //Process outputData
    }
```

Also there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332548/rapi-dll-opennetcf-invoke-example) but does not provide any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378509/killing-a-wince-device-process-from-a-desktop-app?rq=1). In a nutshell; There is no direct way, I need to create a Win32 dll with C where call to WINAPI will be made and deploy it to \Windows folder. After that I can use it with `RAPI.Invoke()`.

Also [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20120112083707/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/07/27/HOWTORetrieveTheDeviceIDFromTheDesktop.aspx) is the link to article containing implementation.